# Image manipulation in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, image-manipulation

I need to create a simple mobile app in React Native for manipulate images from the gallery and the camera. I searched it everywhere, but didn't found any proper solution for this, just libraries for cropping/rotating/etc.

I only want to put own filter on pictures (like a simple national flag with opacity).

Is there any library for bare/expo RN to edit image pixels, or is there any solution to convert an image to a bitmap then convert back to an image and save it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating, flipping (mirroring), resizing, and cropping are all options available in this package: [@oguzhnatly/react-native-image-manipulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@oguzhnatly/react-native-image-manipulator). You can manipulate the image supplied by URI.